# How can I do nextDouble() with a scanner, but for a string instead of a double?

Tags: java

This is part of my program:

```
System.out.println("Type '1' to continue.");
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
double Confirm = s1.nextDouble();
```

Later in the program I have:

```
if (Confirm == 1) {
        System.out.println("");
```

The goal of this is that somebody confirms that they are ready to continue with the code by typing "1" and pressing enter, then it runs the rest of the code. How can I edit the Scanner so that it takes a string input, and then edit the if statement so that it checks for that specific string?

Eg. "Type 'Enter' to continue." And the user types "Enter" and it runs the rest of the code.

Comment: Since you seem not to know how to go read the Scanner API, I'll mention that you'll later need to compare your string like this `input.equals("Enter")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Scanner`'s `nextLine` method

```
String confirm = s1.nextLine();
if (confirm.equalsIgnoreCase("Enter")) {
    //continue code
}
```